# Get current theme colors for SharePoint Online site in SPFx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, theme, typescript

I have a SharePoint Online site with green theme color currently set. In my SPFx webpart I want to be able to get the current theme color (primary, secondary and tertiary) in TypeScript code. Below are the approaches I tried.

**Approach 1**

```
import { getTheme, loadTheme } from '@uifabric/styling';
const theme = getTheme();
const pivotItemStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
    borderColor: theme.palette.themePrimary,
    borderWidth: "1px",
    borderStyle: "solid"
};
```

But `theme.palette.themePrimary` return blue color rather than green.

**Approach 2**

I tried using `DefaultPalette.themePrimary` but it still gives me blue color.

This [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-theme-colors-in-your-customizations) gives CSS equivalents like

```
.button {
  /* ... */
  background-color: "[theme: themePrimary, default: #0078d7]";
  border-color: "[theme: themePrimary, default: #0078d7]";
  /* ... */
}
```

How can I get current site theme color in SPFx webpart using TypeScript?

Comment: Did you followed all the steps given in [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-theme-colors-in-your-customizations#use-theme-colors-in-your-customizations)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the official documentation, [Use theme colors in your SharePoint Framework customizations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-theme-colors-in-your-customizations),

> When you scaffold a new SharePoint Framework client-side web part, by default, it uses the fixed blue palette.

And you need to follow the steps described at [Use theme colors in your customizations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-theme-colors-in-your-customizations#use-theme-colors-in-your-customizations) with the necessary adjustments to have the web part use theme colors instead.

**Additional references**:

1. [How to use Theme Colors in SPFX Web Parts](https://n8d.at/how-to-use-theme-colors-in-spfx-web-parts/).
2. [SharePoint themes and colors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/design/themes-colors).

**Update**:

Additionally, we can get the global variable `__themeState__` from SharePoint Context which contains all defined color and slots used by the theme. You can leverage that to use it in your typescript file.

Check below references on how to use `__themeState__`:

1. [How to get the current theme in a spfx webpart using the new ts based styling approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768206/how-to-get-the-current-theme-in-a-spfx-webpart-using-the-new-ts-based-styling-ap)
2. [How to use Theme Colors in SPFX Web Parts](https://n8d.at/how-to-use-theme-colors-in-spfx-web-parts/) - Check "Bonus Content" section.

Comment: I went through all the links in your answer. They all seem to give me the CSS option. I need to be able to access theme color in TypeScript code. Is there any way to fetch that?

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting why you need this in ts file? you can create a class in CSS file and apply those classes to your html elements in ts file.

Comment: In the example in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58672599/1047998), we need to add style in TypeScript for tabs inside `Pivot`. For this scenario I am unable to figure out how to add classes. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: As I mentioned in **Update** section in my answer, you can leverage the `__themeState__` to get the current theme and colors used in SharePoint site and you can use them in your webpart.

Answer (score 0):

This post helped as I have been through lots of blogs. Below is a snapshot of my code that worked!

```
      const spTheme:any = (window as any).__themeState__.theme;
      const theme: ITheme = createTheme({
        palette:spTheme,
      });
      const [timeStampState, setTimeStampState] = React.useState({
        Created: "",
        Author: "",
        Modified: "",
        Editor: "",
      });
      const style = mergeStyleSets({
        timeStampContainer: {
          backgroundColor: "rgb(243, 242, 241)",
          padding: "1rem",
          margin: "1rem 0 0 12rem",
          width: "86%",
        },
        labelStyle: { color: `${theme.palette.themePrimary} !important`, fontWeight: "bold" },
      });
```

Below is the import:

```
import {
  createTheme,
  getTheme,
  IStackStyles,
  ITheme,
  Label,
  mergeStyleSets,
  Stack,
} from "office-ui-fabric-react";
```